# How to use variables in PostgreSQL in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

My Sounds table has 7 columns: `Start_Time`, `End_Time`, `Salience_Label`, `Class_label`, `Bitrate`, `Bitdepth`, `Samplerate`.

I want to insert some values into this table with the command

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Sounds VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(start_time, end_time, salience_label, class_label, samplerate, bitrate, bitdepth))



try:
   conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
   cursor = conn.cursor()

.... doing staff for getting values for my variables ...

   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Sounds VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(start_time, end_time, salience_label, class_label, samplerate, bitrate, bitdepth))
   print "Connected!\n"
except:
 print "I am unable to connect to the database"

cursor.close()
conn.close()
print('Close conection')
```

Comment: And how does it fail exactly?

Comment: when i check the table Sounds  there are no values in the table.I have also a     
             except:
   print "I am unable to connect to the database" 
 and at the terminal i got this message.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be ? for parameter replacement in cursor.execute instead of %s?

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question. Also, give a bit more context, as even though the failure occurs on `cursor.execute`, the error/mistake/omission causing it is probably earlier. (How do you obtain `cursor`?)

Comment: Im using  
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

and after i do some things to get the right values for my variables.After this i execute 
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Sounds VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",(start_time, end_time, salience_label, class_label, samplerate, bitrate, bitdepth))

Comment: @ChristopherMahan apparently not, per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235686/psycopg2-insert-into-table-with-placeholders

Comment: @AneokoenaAneokoena Could you edit your last comment into your question so it's preserved? Looks like we'll need a bit more context, anyway.

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While testing do not catch exceptions. Make the parameters a single tuple as Psycopg will adapt it to a record. Use `mogrify` to check what is being sent to the server:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
cursor = conn.cursor()

insert = "insert into Sounds values %s"
parameters = (
    start_time, end_time, salience_label, 
    class_label, samplerate, bitrate, bitdepth
)

print cursor.mogrify(insert, (parameters,))
cursor.execute(insert, (parameters,))

conn.commit()
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

BTW, the good practice is to name the columns which will receive the data like in:

```
insert into t (col_a, col_b) values (1, 'a')
```

That will avoid some problems.

Comment: THX MAN IT IS WORKING FINALLYYYYY !