# Python syntax error for executemany function

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert data into my database with python, but there's a syntax error in my query. I'm trying to get the code to take a list and be able to add the list into a row in a postgresql table. I've looked up some ways to add a list into a table and some of them had the '?' in it. I don't know what it means and I don't know why it might be causing the error. The error it's giving me is:

```
syntax error at or near ","
LINE 1: INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Here's my code.

```
var_string = ', '.join('?' * len(items_list))
query_string = 'INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (%s);' % var_string
cur.executemany(query_string, items_list)
```

Comment: Are you sure question marks are used? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235686/psycopg2-insert-into-table-with-placeholders   Also http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/sql.html

Comment: Also, you're executing a single query, not many.

Comment: I don't know I found the code at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316176/insert-list-into-my-database-using-python)

Comment: The link that you refer to is for sqlite, but you use postgresql. Are you sure they have the same Python interface?

Comment: Well, by  judging the errors the console is giving me I don't believe they have they same interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found the answer to my question. So I was able to find another way to add a list to my table. I first hard coded the query and I learned that '?' marks are used for another framework, not postgresql. For postgresql I needed to use %s. I replace the question marks with '%s' character and it worked. The next thing I did was to fix make a less hard coded version. Here it is:

```
items = [data] // items is the list we are trying to add to the db table
copy_string = re.sub(r'([a-z])(?!$)', r'\1,', '%s' * len(items)) // len of items list is 7
final_string = re.sub(r'(?<=[.,])(?=[^\s])', r' ', copy_string)
query_string = 'INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (%s);' % final_string
cur.execute(query_string, items)
```

The output for the query string should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
```

Each '%s' character takes in a value from the list. The code takes in a list and adds them into a row in the db table.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters for PyGreSQL are described by format, either by name or by position:

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (%(id)d, %(name)s, %(date)s)'
cur.execute(query_string, dict(
    id = 1, name = 'Cap Lee', date = datetime.date.today()))
```

or

```
query_string = 'INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (%d, %s, %s)'
cur.execute(query_string, (1, 'Cap Lee', datetime.date.today()))
```